# Infinite loop when installing R package

Tags: r, installation, package, rstudio, gdata

Sometimes, when I try installing an R package, it enters an infinite loop and I have to interrupt R.

I am using RStudio 2022.12.0 Build 353, with R version 4.2.2, on Windows 11.

It already happened to me with other packages. I manage to install the package from the command line, using e.g.:

```
Rscript -e "install.packages('gdata', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

But it's a recurring problem on RStudio so I'd like to understand what's happening and how to fix it.

Here is my output (I have the same problem if I first detach all loaded packages):

```
> install.packages("gdata")
Installation du package dans ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library’
(car ‘lib’ n'est pas spécifié)
installation du package source ‘gdata’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/gdata_2.18.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1054317 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

Le chargement a nécessité le package : NLP
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.2 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.4.0      ✔ purrr   1.0.0 
✔ tibble  3.1.8      ✔ dplyr   1.0.10
✔ tidyr   1.2.1      ✔ stringr 1.5.0 
✔ readr   2.1.3      ✔ forcats 0.5.2 
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ ggplot2::annotate() masks NLP::annotate()
✖ dplyr::arrange()    masks plyr::arrange()
✖ purrr::compact()    masks plyr::compact()
✖ dplyr::count()      masks plyr::count()
✖ dplyr::failwith()   masks plyr::failwith()
✖ dplyr::id()         masks plyr::id()
✖ dplyr::mutate()     masks plyr::mutate()
✖ dplyr::rename()     masks plyr::rename()
✖ dplyr::summarise()  masks plyr::summarise()
✖ dplyr::summarize()  masks plyr::summarize()
Le chargement a nécessité le package : Hmisc
Le chargement a nécessité le package : lattice
Le chargement a nécessité le package : survival
Le chargement a nécessité le package : Formula
Le chargement a nécessité le package : stats

Attachement du package : 'stats'

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:dplyr':

    filter, lag


Attachement du package : 'Hmisc'

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:xtable':

    label, label<-

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:dplyr':

    src, summarize

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:plyr':

    is.discrete, summarize

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:base':

    format.pval, units

Le chargement a nécessité le package : SparseM

Attachement du package : 'SparseM'

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:base':

    backsolve


Attachement du package : 'pastecs'

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:rms':

    specs

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:dplyr':

    first, last

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:tidyr':

    extract

Le chargement a nécessité le package : grid
Le chargement a nécessité le package : Matrix

Attachement du package : 'Matrix'

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:tidyr':

    expand, pack, unpack


Attachement du package : 'survey'

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:rms':

    calibrate

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:Hmisc':

    deff


Attachement du package : 'plotly'

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:Hmisc':

    subplot

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:stats':

    filter

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:ggplot2':

    last_plot

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:plyr':

    arrange, mutate, rename, summarise

Le chargement a nécessité le package : MASS
Le chargement a nécessité le package : grDevices
Le chargement a nécessité le package : graphics

Attachement du package : 'graphics'

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:plotly':

    layout

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:survey':

    dotchart

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:Matrix':

    image

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:SparseM':

    image


Attachement du package : 'MASS'

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:plotly':

    select

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:dplyr':

    select


Attachement du package : 'memisc'

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:plotly':

    rename, style

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:Matrix':

    as.array

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:Hmisc':

    %nin%, Mean, html

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:stats':

    contr.sum, contr.treatment, contrasts

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:dplyr':

    collect, recode, rename, syms

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:purrr':

    %@%

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:tibble':

    view

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:ggplot2':

    syms

Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:NLP':

    annotation, content, content<-

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:plyr':

    rename

L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:base':

    as.array

Installation du package dans 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library'
(car 'lib' n'est pas spécifié)
installation du package source 'gdata'

essai de l'URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/gdata_2.18.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1054317 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB

Le chargement a nécessité le package : NLP
[etc., infinite loop]
```

Comment: It seems very confusing that you are trying to install `gdata` but the output looks like it's loading `NLP` I don't see how those packages are related. Did you customize the `install.packages` function? What if you call `utils::install.packages("gdata")` directly?

Comment: Damn, I am not able to reproduce my bug. Now that I have installed it from the command line, when I remove the package and reinstall it simply using `install.packages("gdata")` it works fine. But I didn't customize the function so I think what you suggest is not a solution.

Comment: Well RStudio masks the base `install.packages` function so it's possible calling the `utils::` version directory might still work. But otherwise you must have some configuration in your RStudio setup that automatically tries to open packages. It's going to be hard to help any further without any sort of reproducible example.

Comment: How do you know that `install.packages` is masked? Can I check this on RStudio? I am using a .Rprofile that loads packages, this may be the culprit?

Comment: If you just type `install.packages` in the console without parenthesis you can see the code. In RStudio you see `.rs.callAs` which is the rstudio wrapper for some functions.  It doesn't match what you see when you run `utils::install.packages`. But yes, automatically loading packages in an .Rprofile can be problematic especially since R can't update packages after they are loaded if they use DLLs or SOs. You might be able to get away with it if you only load them during interactive sessions. Hard to say for sure without a reproducible example.